# Android RTP/RTCP Stack

Tags: android, rtp, rtcp

I'm looking for a Stack/Library which offers me a full utilizing of all Header-Fields of the RTP- and RTCP-Protocol under Android.
I don't know if this is important, but I want to combine it with the JAIN-SIP Stack which I'm using for SIP and SDP.

Have anyone any experience or any suggestions?

The [android.net.rtp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/package-summary.html) is not really what I'm looking for, cause as far as I understood it is not offering me the possibility to read the RTCP reports.

Thanks for your help in advance :-)

Daniel

Comment: Did you find anything?