# android RTP/RTCP java based implementation

Tags: android, sip, rtp, rtcp

I've been searching for any java based RTP/RTCP library to be used in an android application but couldn't find any yet. As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479304/android-rtp-rtcp-stack) answer, [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/package-summary.html) library doesn't provide access to RR/SR reports, even I think it doesn't even provide support for RTCP also.

Many questions I found related to RTP/RTCP were closed as off topic. Couldn't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

I used https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming and it was working (on Android Kitkat at least), I was performing phone to phone streaming. I don't know how well it performs now.

Use